# JAVA(TM) binary has stopped working while ant converts .jmx to .jtl

Tags: java, html, apache, ant, jmeter

I'm trying to generate HTML reports of jmeter files using apache ant. while running the test .jmx file tries to convert itself into .jtl file, at that time java binary has not working pop appears and build fails.

```
D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras>ant -Dtest=RetailerPor
tal
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
Buildfile: D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml
run:
     [echo] funcMode = false
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2
.13\extras\RetailerPortal.jmx ==> D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-
2.13\extras\RetailerPortal.jtl
_message_xalan:
xslt-report:
BUILD FAILED
D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml:132: input f
ile D:\softwares\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\RetailerPortal.jtl
 does not exist
Total time: 17 seconds
```

Comment: JMX is a test plan and JTL is results file?  what do you mean by converting jmx to jtl?

Answer (score 1):

According to the output it fails during execution of the JMeter test, most likely due to low [Java Heap Size value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm) (-Xmx256M). Check out *jmeter.log* file - it usually contains all the necessary information.

Add the following line to `<jmeter>` section of your *build.xml* file:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xmx1234M"/>
```

or set it via [ANT_OPTS environment variable](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) on OS level like:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1234M
```

Replace `1234` with memory size (in megabytes) you want to make available to JMeter (I would go for 70% - 80% of your total physical RAM amount)

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for more JMeter tweaks, tips and tricks

Comment: This works!! I spent whole day on JMeter 3.2 and got it working after un-commenting this section in build.xml in Jmeter\Extras folder.     Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the RAM size works fine.

Comment: Increasing the RAM size in build.xml configuration works fine. 
<jvmarg value="-Xmx4096m"/>

Comment: Uncomment the following settings in build.xml will also resolve the issue
            <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
            <jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>

Answer (score -3):

Please check about `Test.jtl` file which is created in `apacheant\bin`. You might have created a new test documet and replaced its name with Test.jtl simply... Try to open it and save as it with `.jtl` extension... Make sure you've removed `.txt`.

Comment: Explanation is unclear. Please provide clear steps to take and how these will solve the problem.