# "java(tm) binary has stopped working" error while running jmeter tests using ant via command prompt

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, build-automation

I am getting following error while trying to run my jmeter tests using Ant via command prompt.

[image]

When I click on 'view problem details', I get following error.

```
*Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: java.exe
  Application Version:  8.0.1210.13
  Application Timestamp:    584f5bdd
  Fault Module Name:    java.exe
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.1210.13
  Fault Module Timestamp:   584f5bdd
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00009724
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt*
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Command Prompt error message: 

C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras>ant
Buildfile: C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\build.xml
run:`enter code here`
   [echo] funcMode = false
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\T
est.jmx ==> C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\Test.jtl
_message_xalan:
xslt-report:
BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\build.xml:124: input file C:\apach
e-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\Test.jtl does not exist

Answer (score 0):

As I see from error message you have posted on question, it's a typo...

This:

> C:\apach e-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\Test.jtl

Needs to be:

> C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\extras\Test.jtl

Difference:

apach e-jmeter-3.1 >> apache-jmeter-3.1

Comment: sorry Ivan yes. Thank you for pointing it out. It was due to copying error message from CMD and pasting it in Notepad.

Comment: i am still getting the same error. Would you be able to suggest any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command window in Administrator mode and this should work.

[image]

Comment: tried running command prompt as Admin but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `<jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m"/>` line under `<jmeter>` tag in build.xml works like Charm :)

Refer this for more details:-
[Jmeter Java memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028124/javatm-binary-has-stopped-working-while-ant-converts-jmx-to-jtl)